# When to use "smaller" or "less"

Tags: grammar

I have a phrase:
"The amount of junk is getting...".  Should I end it with "smaller" or "less".

What is the general rule for using them?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for using 'small' is in reference to the size of something. So, for example

> The pile of junk has gotten smaller

Less is used in cases where there is a lower amount of something that does not have defined quantities. You cannot accurately quantize 'junk'

> There is less junk than before

You would use fewer if you had a way of quantizing the subject of discussion. For example:

> There are fewer bags of junk than before

As a 'bag' is a discrete quantity.

In the case of your particular sentence however, neither fit very well. I would instead say

> The amount of junk is **decreasing**

Or, perhaps

> The **pile/heap** of junk is getting smaller

Or even

> The **bin/skip/room** (full) of junk is getting emptier